# sxssf-workbook-createsheet-fails-on-linux-environment (OEL 8.5), Solaris 11.4

Tags: apache-poi, xlsx

SXSSFWorkbook workbook.createSheet() method fails on a linux-environment(OEL 8.5) without throwing any kind of meaningful error (it's just hanging).

Strangely, the same method on the XSSFWorkbook createSheet class works fine. Below are the snippets of code. Has anyone experienced a similar issue before?

```
final SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(new XSSFWorkbook(), 100, true, true);
workbook.setCompressTempFiles(true);
Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet 1"); //this method fails

final XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet 1"); // this works fine
```

we are using the apache POI 4.1.2 version. This same code is working fine in windows environment. verified the fonts below, they are already installed. Any idea what is missing in Linux environment please let me know. Any pointers (OR) any logs in the Linux where we can get more details, please share.

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fontconfig

Comment: similar to the https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65260

Comment: It definitely should not simply hang. It should throw an exception if there is an issue. Maybe it has resource problems and so is very time consuming. Have you tried it having `compressTmpFiles` and `useSharedStringsTable` both `false`? Logs you could look in at first are: `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/messages`.

Comment: @ Axel Richter, we are trying to export very small data set. I have not Yet tried with compressTmpFiles and useSharedStringsTable as false. when we tested in OEL 8.2 its working fine in our environment. same code is working fine for lot of Customers. but for some Customer with OEL 8.5 we had this issue. I am using the custom TempFileCreationStrategy to ensure weblogic server is writing the file to a directory it has full access to. it's creating a *.gz file in the POI files DIR. Weblogic out logs does not show any errors.

Comment: Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet 1"); is not getting executed, if we add traces next to this line, they are not printed in the log. After this line, only finally() code is getting executed. Even if we add ex.printstacktrace() nothing is printed in the logs. Verified the weblogic out.log, and we don't see any exceptions in the log.

Comment: Do a thread dump when it is hanging and see where the code is blocking at? My hunch is it's something in the JVM....

Comment: @ Axel Richter, @Gagravarr - Thanks for your help on this issue.  Verified the /var/log/syslog and /var/log/messages logs, there are no errors in these logs. Testing with compressTmpFiles and useSharedStringsTable both false. I will keep posted the update.

Comment: Trigger a hang, then do a JVM thread dump

Comment: Tested with compressTmpFiles and useSharedStringsTable both false and still we are getting the same issue.  @ Gagravarr - trying to get the thread dumps now.

Comment: @Gagravarr - As per the traces Apache POI SXSSFWorkbook.createSheet()
is failing on Oracle Linux 8.5. I reviewed the thread dumps there is blocked/
waiting threads related to excel export. Have some new findings -
If the Linux console (from which the weblogic services are started) is exited
the export to Excel fails. If this is being performed while the
console is still open and active, then the issue cannot be replicated. please let me know what do you think about  about this issue.

Comment: What method(s) is it showing as blocked on in the thread dumps?

Comment: @Gagravarr - sorry for the typo.. I reviewed the thread dumps there is NO blocked/ waiting threads related to excel export.

Comment: So what are the threads doing that are hanging during the Excel export via POI?

Comment: @Gagravarr - no thread is hanging in the JVM thread dump. Thread dumps looks fine. I looks like an OS issue. we are still analyzing from OEL 8.5 side.

Comment: Solaris 11.4 also we have the same issue.As per the traces Apache POI
SXSSFWorkbook.createSheet() is failing on Solaris 11.4.

Comment: Do we need to install any fonts on the linux box(OEL8.5)? we have checked for sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install fontconfig. Any additional fonts are required (OR) installed.

Comment: @Gagravarr - The java.io.tmpdir. var/tmp as java.io.tmpdir, but it has not full permissions to read and write. create a new tmp dir under /u01/tmp and given full permissions to that new tmp DIR.

The export to excel works if I add the tmpdir parameter to server start from weblogic admin console -Djava.io.tmpdir=/u01/tmp

Comment: Even though i am using the custom TempFileCreationStrategy and writing into another temp dir, the Apache POI looks like it is looking for java.io.tmpdir. if there are not permissions given to this DIR, the Code hangs there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the -Djava.io.tmpdir=/u01/tmp  -Djava.awt.headless=true to the weblogic start params fixed this issue.

Please make sure to give full permissions to the /u01/tmp dir.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).